# Combine vector elements below a given threshold value

Tags: r

I have a vector of values. I'd like to remove values below a certain threshold and add them together with the previous value and the value immediately afterwards. So, if element `n` is below the threshold, I add together elements `n-1`, `n`, and `n+1` and remove the latter two from the vector. Included below is an example.

Here's my dummy data.

```r
# Dummy data
foo <- c(4561L, 57L, 1773L, 17623L, 6030L, 5L, 3353L, 3L, 270L, 4L, 
         267L, 15L, 2L, 12L, 348L, 101L, 367L, 3780L, 491L, 18L, 111L, 
         13L, 200L, 8L, 8449L, 34L, 54L, 4L, 6L, 12L, 5L, 14740L, 12208L, 
         1L, 4L, 1599L, 2108L, 13073L, 51L, 2L, 19L, 4L, 109L, 10L, 1087L, 
         4L, 10201L, 19L, 196L, 27L, 1856L, 9L, 6364L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 297L, 
         14731L, 1L, 15L, 323L, 107L, 14547L, 1419L, 6L, 28L, 4L, 10L, 
         20L, 20L, 4868L, 9896L, 6827L, 4306L, 3025L)

# Look at vector
foo
#>  [1]  4561    57  1773 17623  6030     5  3353     3   270     4   267
#> [12]    15     2    12   348   101   367  3780   491    18   111    13
#> [23]   200     8  8449    34    54     4     6    12     5 14740 12208
#> [34]     1     4  1599  2108 13073    51     2    19     4   109    10
#> [45]  1087     4 10201    19   196    27  1856     9  6364     3     7
#> [56]     3   297 14731     1    15   323   107 14547  1419     6    28
#> [67]     4    10    20    20  4868  9896  6827  4306  3025
```

Next, I set the threshold and my loop counter, `i`.

```r
# Set threshold value & iterator
threshold <- 300
i <- 1
```

Finally, I loop through `foo`. If the element is less than `threshold`, it is added to the elements before and after it and then it is removed from `foo` along with the value immediately after it.

```r
# Loop through vector
while(i < length(foo)){
  if(foo[i] < threshold & i > 1){
    foo[i - 1] <- foo[i -1] + foo[i] + foo[i + 1]
    foo <- foo[-c(i, i+1)]
  }else{
    i <- i + 1    
  }
}
```

The desired result is as follows:

```r
# Look at result
foo
#>  [1]  6391 17623 10777  3780  9405 14740 12213  1599  2108 13268 20073
#> [12] 14747 14977  1507  4868  9896  6827  4306  3025
```

This solution works, but is not vectorised and seems cludgy. Is there a more elegant vectorised approach to solving this problem?

Comment: Why do you want it vectorized? Is the solution too slow? Looks to me like you need a sliding window and I'm not sure how to vectorize that, especially for neighboring values that meet your criterion for summing.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik While I appreciate that loops are a critical part of R, this solution just seems at odds with the usual sleek aesthetic of the language. It will need to be quick given that I'll use it with huge datasets, but at this point it's not clear that it's too slow. (And even if it was, I could always implement a similar solution in C++/Rcpp.) Mostly, I was just curious if there was a more elegant way of solving the problem that I'd missed.